# How to set up a limit or an alarm on CloudWatch for Amazon Comprehend

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms, amazon-comprehend

I'm planning on using Amazon Comprehend for some trial project, but I would like to stay within limits of the free tier. For this reason, I need to set up an alarm on CloudWatch to get informed when I reach said limits.

However, I am unable to select "Amazon Comprehend" from the list of services to monitor.

Can I get some assistance?

Answer (score 1):

From [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/), the limits for **Amazon Comprehend** are:

- 50 K units of text (5M characters) for each API per month (50,000 units @ $0.0001/unit = $5 of value)
- 5 Topic Modeling Jobs up to 1MB each per month for the first 12 months (5 @ $1 = $5 value)

So, the free tier provides up to $10 of value each month.

Accordingly to [AWS Services That Publish CloudWatch Metrics - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/aws-services-cloudwatch-metrics.html), Amazon Comprehend *does not* publish metrics to Amazon CloudWatch.

Therefore, your best method would be to monitor the **Top Free Tier Services by Usage** dashboard in the AWS management console to keep a track of Free Tier usage. You should also receive an email when a Free Tier quantity is close to being exceeded.